Best way to test functionality without mistakes when deadline is tight?
What is the best test approach for blackbox/functional testing when there is very less time to test and feature has to go live in production next day.
without leaving out important test scenarios or making mistakes in testing?

Your question is quite open, it is basically asking "how to be effective and efficient as tester". One could write a book about this. I suggest adding more information about your context, your team's tools and skills, what is your tight deadline (a business reason, a regulatory reason), and what information you want to learn from your testing sessions.

A short answer - follow the principles of Test Driven Development - i.e. write the tests first, then the write code, run the tests, fix any problems, check the coverage, enhance the tests to reach the desired level of coverage, etc.
However, this will likely only work if your organisation already has invested the time and effort in:

Good test tools
Automated testing on representative hardware &/or virtualised environments.
Existing test coverage of existing code at or very near 100%
The ability to roll back breaking or faulty changes after they have been deployed.
Generate the people skills to:

Capture clear, unambiguous, testable specifications.
Respond to queries on those specifications in real time.
Quickly generate & validate test cases.
Code quickly to those specifications.
Debug and address failures.
Review the changes and address any issues.
Block bad changes regardless of the pressure to deploy now.



Even then there is no way that you can be 100% sure of capturing all possible faults as, e.g. you will not be able to perform tests such as long term soak testing in the target time period.
